# Simple test app deploys to Heroku but won't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm new to Heroku. I tried pushing a simple test Rails 3.1.1 app to Heroku. The only changes that I made to it from the "new" Rails app template was to create a Home controller and point the root to `home#index`. I also ran

```
rails g scaffold Mark type:string start_time:datetime end_time:datetime subject:string measure:float special_event:boolean flag:boolean in_progress:boolean
```

so that I could run a database migration and test to make sure all showed up properly. The final change that I made was to the Gemfile, which now looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I followed the Heroku tutorial for this. The push worked, there were no errors reported. I ran `heroku rake db:migrate` `heroku addons:add logging`. I also deleted `public/index.html` from the app. When I run the app locally with `rails server`, it works fine. I also can manually navigate to the "marks" index, per the scaffold.

When I run `heroku open`, all I get is the standard `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` Rails page. `heroku logs` shows me nothing at all.

What am I doing wrong here? This is about as simple as test cases get, yet I can't get it to work after fiddling with it for hours, creating new apps, deleting this app and trying again, trying to deploy another app, etc.

Comment: Is there _nothing_ in the heroku logs at all?  You should at least see the requests you are making.

Comment: Nothing at all. I type in `heroku logs`, there is a pause, and then I see the next command prompt.

Comment: I would contact Heroku support - something is not right here.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably do that. Thanks.

Comment: It will be the asset pipeline that is enabled by default that is causing your problem set `config.assets.enabled = false` in your application.rb. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that Rails 3.1 asset pipeline doesn't work 'out of the box' on Bamboo-mri-1.9.2 which is the default when you do `heroku create`.

The solution is to do `heroku create --stack cedar` and then push - all will be fine then :)

Comment: note, when you migrate to cedar will need to do heroku run rake db:migrate. You'll get http://glowing-stone-9665.herokuapp.com/marks when you fire it up.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea what the problem was and may never have come across that.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this just to see if this works:

```
rails new stackoverflow
cd stackoverflow/
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'all'
git remote add origin git@github.com:noahc/stackoverflow.git #you'll need to change this
git push origin master
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

If that doesn't work, then it is something to do with your local machine. I just ran through this and it works on my end. See: http://gentle-dawn-1050.heroku.com. If this doesn't fail, I'd try making the changes to the GemFile and see if you can get it to fail that way.

Comment: Hmm... That works. Let me nuke my Heroku acct again and try once more with a vanilla app with a migration.

Comment: If I add a migration and run `heroku rake:db:migrate`, then the migration appears to go well. `heroku open` shows me the "We're sorry..." page again, however. My gem file contains nothing but the default source line, `gem 'rails', '3.1.1'` and `gem 'pg'`. Is `pg` not the right gem to use as the database adaptor? Here's the repo: `https://github.com/ccheaton/herokutest`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Looks like you got to the bottom of your issue, but for future problem-havers I want to point out that it could be a discrepancy between the database you use for your local app and the one behind the live app. In my case, my local database was populated, and my Heroku site was empty, since l I didn't properly migrate.

This problem only became apparent when I ran "rake db:reset" in the terminal, (to clear all the data in my local app's database), after which I was able to easily find the bugs in my code.

Conclusion: if the information in your database is negligible, I would suggest clearing it and troubleshooting from there, because it could be that the site you've deployed just doesn't have data yet, and maybe your code doesn't properly handle that kind of exception.......