# pages available on localhost not available on heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've just started making apps in rails. When I run my local server, links to some of the static pages I have made work fine (stored in the apps/views/pages/ folder). However, when I successfully push this app to heroku and attempt to navigate to those pages, I get the standard "sorry something went wrong" message. I have modified the index page so I know that those updates are working. Any help would be appreciated.

i went through http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html, and [Simple test app deploys to Heroku but won't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823020/simple-test-app-deploys-to-heroku-but-wont-run)

i'm running on the cedar stack and have run heroku run rake db:migrate

when i do
    heroku run rake routes 
it returns:

```
pages_home GET /pages/home(.:format)    pages#home
pages_contact GET /pages/contact(.:format) pages#contact
pages_about GET /pages/about(.:format)   pages#about
```

I'm running rails 3.2, but ruby 1.8.7. I'm on osx lion.

Comment: ran heroku logs and this time paid closer attention - the error is ActionView::Template::Error, my css isn't being precompiled. So I guess I'll be doing that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the error was that I didn't precompile my CSS. So all you have to do is precompile it. To do this just type `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, then do all the normal git commit, push, and heroku push business.